# How to control halftone dots and ink density in Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript, epson

How to control halftone dots and ink density in Ghostscript? I'm using a Epson SC T-7270PS model and I'm trying to print without any RIP software and it has failed so far. Does anyone know how to control the screen frequency and ink density settings in Ghostscript? Is it even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sethalftone operators in PostScript to set the halftone screen. See section 7.4 of the 3rd edition PLRM.